# adding data to existing ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the ggplot2 package on the cars dataset. I have created a grid based on the manufacturer and color coded by class..

What I would like to do is:
add to each plot in the grid from the dataset mdat.Data should be represented as data points.
The output I would like to see is the data in mdat is to be represented in each plot as dots, the class should be added to the legend, I would like each point to be represented with a different color and shape. I am not sure how this can be done and any help is appreciated.

Thanks so much!

```
## Sample data
   p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=hwy, y=cty))
   p<- p + facet_grid(. ~ manufacturer) + facet_wrap(~manufacturer) 
   p<- p + geom_point(aes(colour = class), size = 7)
   p<- p + scale_colour_brewer()
   p<- p + geom_point(shape = 1, size = 7,  alpha = I(0.7))
   print(p) 



 ##now add on the randomn portfolios on another grid
   hwy = c("35", "40", "25")
   cty = c("20", "25", "10")
   mdat <- data.frame(hwy,cty)
   mdat$class <- c("generic1", "generic2", "generic3")
```

[image]

Comment: Just a couple of comments: (1) it's not a great idea to use a gradient color scale for discrete values (e.g., class). (2) Using the color brewer Blues set creates a situation where the lighter blues disappear into the background, forcing you to use a shape that has a border. Better to use the [Set1 or Dark2](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/) (3) You're using `facet_grid(...)` and `facet_wrap(..)` together; the latter overrides the former. (4) You don't need `I(0.7)`, just `alpha=0.7` will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in your data frame `mdat` don't use the quotes around the numbers because that makes them as characters.

```
mdat <- data.frame(hwy = c(35, 40, 25),
                   cty = c(20, 25, 10))
mdat$class <- c("generic1", "generic2", "generic3")
```

If you need to represent those new point with different colours then class for existing points then it is better to use shapes that allow to set fill, so they use different scale.

```
p+geom_point(data=mdat,aes(hwy,cty,shape=class,fill=class),size=7)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. However I am still unable to get the color as you have on your graph. This is what I have added p<-p+geom_point(data=mdat,aes(hwy,cty,shape=class),size=7)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))
print(p)

Comment: There was mistake in my code - there should be fill=class inside the aes(). I updated answer

Comment: never mind I think i understood I have to add fill as well to the aes...etc. Thanks so much for your help. I do have another quick question. If I want to replace the shapes with actual names like "gen1", "gen2", "gen3" with different colors..what command should i use? Thanks again!

Comment: @hdg - Use `geom_text(...)` for that.